# Search for a string in an array of objects

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a product search engine in my application.

I have this code:

```
func searchStringInProductArray(searchString: String) {
    let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let path = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/json/products.json")
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var productsTmpObjectArray = [Products]()

        productsTmpObjectArray = try decoder.decode([Products].self, from: data)
        productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.code?.contains(searchString))!})
        productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.name?.contains(searchString))!})
        productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.langVersions.name?.contains(searchString))!})
        productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.langVersions?.description?.contains(searchString))!})
        productsObjectArray = productsTmpObjectArray
        collectionView1.reloadData()
    } catch {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: nil, userInfo: ["object": errorMessage(title: "Blad".localized(), description: "problemWithParseData".localized(), buttonTitle: "Ok".localized())])
    }
}
```

and object:

```
struct ChangeTime : Codable {
    let year : Int?
    let month : Int?
    let dayOfMonth : Int?
    let hourOfDay : Int?
    let minute : Int?
    let second : Int?
}

struct Lang : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let code : String?
    let name : String?
}

struct LangVersions : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let parentId : Int?
    let name : String?
    let lang : Lang?
    let description : String?
}

struct Products : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let code : String?
    let name : String?
    let inPieces : Bool?
    let prepDeepFryer : String?
    let langVersions : [LangVersions]?
    let changeTime : ChangeTime?
}
```

The function is called after entering text in TextField:

```
@IBAction func searchProductTextFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    searchStringInProductArray(searchString: searchTextField.text!)
}
```

I have the following errors:

1. productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.langVersions.name?.contains(searchString))!}) - Value of type '[LangVersions]?' has no member 'name'
2. productsTmpObjectArray =  productsTmpObjectArray.filter({($0.langVersions?.description?.contains(searchString))!}) - Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'String'

I would like my search engine to search for all fields at once:

- $0.code?.contains(searchString)
- $0.name?.contains(searchString)
- $0.langVersions.name?.contains(searchString)
- $0.langVersions?.description?contains(searchString)

Comment: `langVersions` is an array, so you will need to use a `.filter` operation on it too. I would suggest that you load that data into Core Data and use it to search.

Comment: could you show me how to make this search engine based on my code? Is this impossible to do in my code?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible, but it probably isn't going to be pretty. I wouldn't try and use `filter`, I would just use some nested loops to create a Set of matching products

Comment: Something like that in the closure (I wrote `contains()` instead of `contains(searchString)`): `if $0.code.contains() { return true }; if $0.name.contains() { return true }; if $0.langueVersions.map({$0.name}).contains() { return true }; if $0.langueVersions.map({$0.description).contains() { return true }
; return false` could do the trick (not tested, might need slight changes to compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't noticed that 'Products' object contains array of 'LangVersions' object. edited version of your method:

```
func searchStringInProductArray(searchString: String) {
    let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let path = URL(string: "")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var productsTmpObjectArray = [Products]()

        productsTmpObjectArray = try decoder.decode([Products].self, from: data)
        productsObjectArray =   productsTmpObjectArray.filter({return ($0.code?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))! || ($0.name?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))! || (($0.langVersions?.filter({($0.name?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))!}))?.count)! > 0 || (($0.langVersions?.filter({($0.description?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))!}))?.count)! > 0 })
        collectionView1.reloadData()
    } catch {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationAlertMessage"), object: nil, userInfo: ["object": errorMessage(title: "Blad".localized(), description: "problemWithParseData".localized(), buttonTitle: "Ok".localized())])
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works correctly. It only draws attention to uppercase and lowercase letters. How to repair it?

Comment: i made the changes. i think you should know about this thing i.e you can easily figure out this kind of issues make both string lowercased and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to search for all values

```
let searchString = "searStr".lowercased()

productsTmpObjectArray = productsTmpObjectArray.filter { ($0.name?.lowercased().contains(searchString))! || ($0.code?.lowercased().contains(searchString))! ||   $0.langVersions?.filter {($0.name?.lowercased().contains(searchString))!}.count != 0 || $0.langVersions?.filter {($0.description?.lowercased().contains(searchString))!}.count != 0 }
```